# Rewrite Rule replace a symbol

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have my website mywebsite.com/this.php?That=Blah+Blah

My rewrite rule is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^That/([A-Za-z0-9-+]+)/?$ this.php?That=$1 [NC]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-+]+)/?$That/$1 [NC]
```

When I type mywebsite.com/Blah+Blah it is working fine.

How can I change the + symbol with - symbol so when I type mywebsite.com/Blah-Blah to have same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new rule for `hyphen to +` conversion:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-(.*)$ /$1\+$2 [L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w+]+)/?$ /this.php?That=$1 [L,QSA,NE]
```

Comment: this works but it also replaces the - symbol with + symbol at the javascript source coude in result the rever not to locate the files. i.e java/this-that.js is converted to java/this+that.js

Comment: Yes it replace `- with +` please specify what you want by providing some examples.

Comment: I want to replace + with - only at the url i.e mywebsite.com/this.php?That=Blah+Blah -> mywesite.com/Blah-Blah I do not want to replace anything at the source code of the page.Only at the URL rewrite rule.

Comment: But how is that URL written on page? Is it `/Blah-Blah` OR `/That/Blah-Blah`?

Comment: it is written /Blah+Blah according to my rewrite rule and I want to change it to /Blah-Blah (the original is /this.php?That=Blah+Blah and with the rule above I have change it to /Blah+Blah)

Comment: But you also wrote: `RewriteRule ^That/([A-Za-z0-9-+]+)/?$ this.php?That=$1 [NC]` in your question that got me confused.

Comment: If you want a URL of `/Blah-Blah` to be rewritten to: `/this.php?That=Blah+Blah` then that is already being done by above rule. Provide some examples for which it doesn't work.

Comment: no it is not working as /Blah-Blah. It is working as /Blah+Blah or /Blah Blah.

Comment: I just tested again these just these 2 rules in my `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` and it gets rewritten to `/this.php?That=blah+blah` Do you have other rules in .htaccess also?

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. The problem was I had to replace -  with + or space at the variable $that = str_replace('-', ' ', $_GET["That"]);